# Difference? "I sleep during the day." and "I sleep by the day."

Tags: differences

What is the difference? Assume I am a night owl, what subtle difference I should be aware of when I think of these two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

*During the day* is correct, *by the day* is not - it's *by day*, though that usage is a little old-fashioned. *In the daytime* is more idiomatic.